# Adding reminder in existing events in a specific google calender in a batch

Tags: google-calendar

I have a calendar in Google calendar that I want all the existing and future events to give me a reminder in my android phone one week before the event. I don't want to add the reminder one by one myself, is there a way to do it in a batch? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way of achieving this is to change your default notification settings for all events on a given calendar. See the Google support article below for instructions on how to do this.

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/83117?hl=en

Here is the relevant part of the Google Support document:

*To change your default notification settings, follow these steps:

1. In the calendar list on the left, click the down-arrow button next
   to the appropriate calendar, then select Reminders and
   notifications.
2. In the Event reminders section, select the reminder method from the
   drop-down menu and enter the corresponding reminder time (between
   zero minutes and four weeks in advance of the event).
3. If you'd like to add additional default reminders, simply click Add
   another reminder.
4. You can also choose to be notified of specific activities on the
   calendar by selecting the appropriate options in the Choose how you
   would like to be notified section.

Once you've made the appropriate changes to your default settings, click Save.*

Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of resurrecting a dead article, here is a link to a Google support document that more closely answers the original question (maybe the previous link used to be better than it is today). [Change or turn off calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Notifications this way work for any items that do not already have notifications of their own (I used this after I imported an iCal from another calendar source).

Current relevant content is:

> Turn notifications on or off
>
> You can choose whether to have
> notifications for events, and whether you want to get notifications
> over email or in your browser.
>
> Open Google Calendar on your computer.
> In the top right, click Settings -> Settings. At the top of the page, click
> the Calendars tab. Next to your calendar's name, click Edit notifications.
> Click Add a notification or edit an existing notification. At the
> bottom of the page, click Save. Note: To get notifications on your
> computer, you need to have Google Calendar open in your browser.